# What should I do with a CONNECT event?

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, proxy

If I create a simple server in Node.JS

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(callback);

httpServer.on('connect', function(req, socket, head){
    console.log('connect');
});

httpServer.listen(3128, '192.168.0.2');
```

What should I do when I receive the `connect` event?

**Background**

- This will be a proxy server, serving HTTP and HTTPS
- Clients connect on port 3128
- When a client makes an HTTPS request the `connect` event is fired

Ideally what I would like to do is, proxy the request to the end server, and then give the client the response.

But I can't see any API for doing that here. The `connect` callback doesn't have the usual arguments of `(request, response)`, instead it accepts `(request, socket, head)`.

**How do I fulfil the request and issue a response?**

Comment: Perhaps look at how [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer rewritten from scratch**

Here is simple example.
`connect` event handler have passed `socket` object which we have to tie with remote connection's socket.

```
httpServer.on('connect', function(req, socket, head) {
  var addr = req.url.split(':');
  //creating TCP connection to remote server
  var conn = net.connect(addr[1] || 443, addr[0], function() {
    // tell the client that the connection is established
    socket.write('HTTP/' + req.httpVersion + ' 200 OK\r\n\r\n', 'UTF-8', function() {
      // creating pipes in both ends
      conn.pipe(socket);
      socket.pipe(conn);
    });
  });

  conn.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Server connection error: " + e);
    socket.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful. I'm talking about serving httpS requests and handling requests made with the CONNECT method

Comment: I see. Answer rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to rewrite, it helped me a LOT :)

Comment: I've edited your answer, it was missing the 200 OK message back to the client, but otherwise working.

Comment: Thank you. I included you fix in the answer with one correction: `socket.write` is async function, and we have to create pipes after header is sent, in callback of `write` function.

Comment: From node 7 documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Comment: What is the `head` parameter for?

Comment: you can also look at this code for a complete working example: https://github.com/cypress-io/debugging-proxy